# Search Keyword from Table field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Below is my table

**Registration**

- Reg_Id
- Name
- Resume

In `Resume` filed, contents of resume are inserted. Now i want to search keyword from that filed.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Registration AS r WHERE Resume LIKE '%Manager%'
```

When I search `Manager` keyword, it gives me records whose resume contains `Manager` keyword,its correct, but when i search `Design` keyword, it gives me records whose resume contains `Designation` keyword. How can i get data of only `Design` keyword? Thanks.

Comment: are you wanting to do an inclusive search or exclusive?

Comment: jus do `select * from table where resume like 'Design'`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want rows where the resume is strictly design then the query would be:

```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.Registration WHERE Resume = 'Design'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create A full-text Index 1st as shown below and then Use the full-text Search to find the right values.

**Create FTS Index**

```
USE DataBase_Name;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ui_RegID ON dbo.Registration(Reg_Id);
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Registration(Resume) 
   KEY INDEX ui_RegID 
GO
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Registration
WHERE CONTAINS(resume,”Design”)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would you suggest using full text search?